# Finding shortest "path" that contain a certain collection of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I have the top graph in the image (unweighted and undirected graph) and I want to find a set of nodes (with the least amount of nodes) so that all of the selected nodes (in red) are connected.

I can assume in this case that there is always a way to reach the "master node" (big one), which means there is always a solution.
My solution for the example is the bottom of the image.

Is there an algorithm for this kind of problem?
I am new to the "graph scene" and I couldn't find any, maybe because I lack the terminology to describe what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: You're basically looking for a subset of the [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem

Comment: Does the "master node" have to be included in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that is probably not optimal but easy to understand and may be enough for your needs.

1. Solve the All Pairs Shortest Path problem using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.
2. With each node as the source, sum the distance to every red node (skip the source node if any red node is unreachable)
3. The master node is the source node from step 2 with the lowest sum.

This only works because the graph is unweighted, which means that the distance is equivalent to the number of nodes in the path.

Comment: There's no need to run Floyd-Warshall to solve the APSP if all edge weights are 1. Simply run a BFS for every node. This is O(n(n+m)) which is slightly better than the runtime of Floyd-Warshall of O(n³) if there are o(n²) many edges. Finding the master node alone also doesn't suffice to solve the problem.